# Change page background after video has loaded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple question that may require a complex answer.

I have used the  tag in HTML5 to make a video background. While the video loads I want the page background to be white. Once the video loads the background should change to black.

The video auto loads and starts automatically once it is loaded.

Is there a way to do this with either a bit of PHP, JavaScript or maybe JQuery?

Comment: You should be able to attach a `load` event to the video element, and change the background when that is triggered.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your markup looks like

```
<video id='myvideo'></video>
```

Try attaching an onload event handler

```
document.getElementById('myvideo').onload = function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

Comment: Good answer, even had the same ID as me, but you beat me by a few seconds. +1

Comment: yeah that was weird, for a moment I thought stackoverflow automatically changed my color 'black' to '#000'

Comment: I would add this to the HTML page or reference it in the page as an external script?